# Excluding some columns in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, select

In the result for

```
SELECT * from myTable WHERE some-condition;
```

I'm interested in 9 of all the 10 columns that exist. The only way out is to specify the 9 columns explicitly ?

I cannot somehow specify just the column I don't want to see?

Comment: It's generally a best practice to always specify the column list vs. a select *.

Comment: it is a good idea to create a stored procedure that lists out a bunch of info about a given table: columns, data types, etc. You can then run this from management studio and quickly cut the column names out and past them into your query. no need to type them in.  I build one based on sp_help (you can view the source code) and added in some things and changed the formatting to suit my needs.

Comment: And how hard is it to add the column names.  In SQL server, I can just drag and drop them from the object browser and I'll bet most other databases havea similar feature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way is to list all 9 columns.

Such as:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9 FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not. An example definition of select list for Sybase can be [found here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1502/html/sqlug/sqlug80.htm), you can easily find others for other DBs

**The reason for that is that the standard methods of selection - "*" (aka all columns) and a list of columns - are [defined operations in relational Algebra](http://www.globalspec.com/reference/44242/203279/11-5-SQL-Choosing-Columns-Rows-and-Order)** whereas the exclusion of columns is not

Also, as mentioned in Joe's comment, it is usually considered good practice to explicitly specify column list as opposed to "*" even when selecting all columns.

The reason for that is that having * in a joined query may cause the query to break if a table schema change introduces identically-named fields in both of the joined tables.

However, when selecting without a join from a very wide and often-mutating table, the above rule may not apply, as having "*" makes for a good change management (your query is one less place to fix and release when adding new columns), especially if you have flexible DB retrieval code that can dynamically deal with a column set from table definition instead of something specified in the code. (e.g., 100% of our extractors and loaders are fully working whenever a new column is added to the DB).

Comment: I'll also point out that in a join at least one field is in the select list twice (the join field). Every bit of information you send takes up space in the network pipeline and adds time to the query, so redundant information should never be sent as a nmatter of best practice.

Answer (score 2):

If you had to (can't think of why), but you could dynamically create this select statement by querying the columns in this table and exclude the one column name in the where clause.

Not worth the performance hit, confusion, and maintenance issues that will come up.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to specify the columns explicitly (as said by Luke it is good practice), and here is the reason:

Let's say that you write some code / scripts around you sql queries. You now have a whooping 50 different selects in various places of your code.

Suddenly you realize that for this new feature you are working on, you need another column (symmetry, you are doing cleanup and realize a column is useless and wasting space, though it is harder).

Now you are in either of this 2 situations:

- You explicitly stated the columns in each and every query: Adding a column is a backward compatible change, just code your new feature and be done with it.
- You used the '*' operator for a few queries: you have to track them down and modify them all. Forget a single one and it will be your grave.

Oh, and did I specify that a query with a '*' selector takes more time to be executed since the DB actually has to query the model and develop the '*' selector ?

Moral: only use the '*' selector when you are checking manually that your columns are fine (at which point you actually need to check everything), in code, just bane them or they'll be your doom.

Comment: Using select * can also expose columns you don't want the user to see when they are added to the database.  Do you really want the user to see who last updated the record in a report? Do you want to show the GUID used for replication to the user?

Comment: Actually that's another point altogether about data exposure. You often select the 'id' and yet it is not displayed. So you often display much less than you retrieve anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't (at least not in any SQL dialect that I'm aware of).

It's good practice to explicitly specify your column names anyway, rather than using `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, you need to specify all 9 out of 10 columns separately - but there's tooling help out there which helps you make this easier!

Check out Red-Gate's [SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Prompt/index.htm) which is an intellisense-add-on for SQL Server Management Studio and Visual Studio.

Amongst a lot of other things, it allows you to type

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

and then go back, put the cursor after the " * ", and press `TAB` - it will then list out all the columns in that table and you can tweak that list (e.g. remove a few you don't need).

Absolutely invaluable - saves hours and hours of mindless typing! Well worth the price of a license, I'd say.

Highly recommended!

Marc

Comment: Don't need the add-on for SSMS: Right click on intended table, Script table As > SELECT to > New Query Editor Window.  Alter columns to suit.

Comment: PLSQL Developer has similar native functionality.

Comment: @rexem: that's quite a bit more work - clicking and mousing around; it works - just not very efficiently....